# Component gets rendered before getting its values

Tags: reactjs

I have an `AuthContext` file for the user info. when I `console.log` the data returning from the api, the `user` is being set properly. However the `AuthContext` component gets rendered **before** the api returns the user's value so on the page that uses the context the user properties are always null.

Any idea on how to solve that?

`AuthContext`:

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class AuthProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {
      name: '',
      isAdmin: false,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      const { data: user } = await axios.get('/api/user/GetUser');
      this.setState(user);
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{this.props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
  }
}

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;

export { AuthProvider, AuthConsumer };
```

`Hedrer` component that call the `AuthContext`:

```
import { AuthConsumer } from '../AuthContext';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import Initial from './Initial';
export default ({ user, children }) => (
  <AuthConsumer>
    {({ user }) => (
      <div css={headerStyles}>
        <div>
          <Welcome name={user.name} />
          <Initial name={user.name} />
        </div>
        {children}
      </div>
    )}
  </AuthConsumer>
);
```

Comment: Can you try `this.setState({ user })` instead of `this.setState(user)`? State change should force React to re-render

Comment: @nbokmans That's it! Thanks! Would you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you accidentally forgot to add the curly brackets to update your state, you are doing

```
this.setState(user);
```

You need to wrap your the arguments to your `setState` call in curly brackets like so:

```
this.setState({ user });
```

Any changes to the state will trigger React to re-render. More information on `setState` can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate